# Help reading this equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding this equation. Its been really long since I read any complex equations. Please see the screenshot below.

Here `A` is all possible attributes, `D` is dictionary of `v:a`. `v` is some value, `a` is attribute,`Zu` is n-gram value of size 4 from a string,

$$\mathcal R_u = \{ \langle a, \{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \} \rangle|a \in \mathcal A \}$$

Note for Moderators: Not sure if I am tagging this correctly. Please update accordingly as I have no clue on where to tag this equation.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for those links. I have updated it now :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal R_u = \{ \langle a, \{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \} \rangle|a \in \mathcal A \}$$

is a *relation*, i.e. a set of *pairs* $\langle a, \{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \} \rangle$ where the first component $a$ belongs to the set $\mathcal A$ of *attributes* and the second component $\{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \}$ is in turn a set.

Example. If for the set of *attributes* we have: $\mathcal A = \{ \text{colour}, \text{weight} \}$, then:

> $$\mathcal R_u = \{ \langle \text{colour}, \{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \} \rangle, \langle \text{weight}, \{v|v \in \mathcal Z_u, a \in \mathcal D(v) \} \rangle \}$$

The issue is (for me) with the definition of the second component: it is the set whose memebers $v$ are in $\mathcal Z_u$, but what "adds" to this condition the expression: $a \in \mathcal D(v)$ ?

Comment: `D` is something like `{blue: colour, black: colour, red: colour, 80Kg: weight}` so if `v = blue` `D(v) = colour`

Comment: also `A = {colour, weight}`